# Where is React Native Expo android folder?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using React native expo and I will install a plugin via github. However, in the documentation, changes are required in the /android/build.gradle folder. But my application does not have such a folder either. Can you help me ?

Github link: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Comment: That library is not compatible with Expo. Expo has its own push notification system.

Comment: The android and ios folders are hidden from you when using the managed workflow. If you want to use them, you will have to eject.

Comment: @Phobos Okay well Why?

Comment: I'm very happy to help you solve a particular problem, but I'm not going to recite documentation for you that is readily available on their website. https://docs.expo.io/

Answer (score 1):

Expo Takes Care of .android & .ios folders. so it doesn't give you those files; but if you're sure you don't want expo, use:
`expo eject`
then, you have to install all expo dependencies which you installed using Expo.
but, if You're just asking for notifications, you may use:
`expo install expo-notifications` and use that you send both server and local notifications.
you may find more info [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/).